# Is it possible to check if any variable is passed from controller without looking at controller? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have this bellow method in my controller but for some reason I can't look at it which variables are passed to my blade view. Can I check if any variable is passed to view or not?

```
public function test()
    {
        $var1 = 'val1';
        $var2 = 'val2';
        return view('test', ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2]);

    }
```

Here in my view file I want to check if any variable exists that is passed from controller?

```
<div>
// check if any variable is exists.
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried php isset($variable)?? it returns true or false

Comment: you could get all the data the view has access to, but you wouldn't know where the data came from ... if you want to check if a variable itself exists that is simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all passed data using `dd`

```
{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}
```

OR You can also do this

```
{{ dd($__data) }}
```